# Image weight higher after upload with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have a problem with paperclip. When I'm uploading an .png image of 507ko, the result is an image of... 2.1Mb, almost 4x bigger.

I only have this problem with PNGs in portrait format. JPGs get a little heavier too but only few bytes.

Also, the problem only appears with my 'extra' format.

This is my code:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
                styles: { extra: "1280x3000>", large: "640x480>", medium: "200x120#"}
```

And the image if you want to try: https://www.groupe-pratique.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Les-chiffres-du-marketing-automation-infographie-1.png

Have you ever had this problem?

**EDIT:**

In fact, the problem doesn't appear only with extra size, but with the other sizes, the difference is too tiny to be seen. The problem is... problematic with big sizes.

**EDIT2:**

I solved the problem by convert the PNG files to JPG. It's not a problem in my case but if you really need a PNG file, I didn't find a solution. :/

Comment: and what the size of your image was before uploading I mean height x width?

Comment: Hi @Nezir, the size is 2000x7096px

Comment: Is the issue a change in dimensions or a change in file size?

Comment: The dimension changes as I would like, but even if the dimension is smaller, the file size increases enormously

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting `convert_options` at model paperclip options like sample belove?  Like  `-quality 80`? or much lover. Please try to manipulate with this option and then upload test file size.

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                  :styles          => { :thumb => '50x50#' },
                  :convert_options => { :thumb => '-quality 80' }
```

Because paperclip using in a background ImageMagick and it have some default settings for manipulating images in process of uploading:
"The default is to use the estimated quality of your input image if it can be determined, otherwise 92. When the quality is greater than 90, then the chroma channels are not downsampled. Use the -sampling-factor option to specify the factors for chroma downsampling."

I am suggesting you to try this convert_options and check the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the more I decrease the quality, the more the weight increases, it's really weird